# PHP: Printing HTML-Friendly Code?

Tags: php, coding-style

I am wondering if there is any technique out there for making HTML code look good when printing that HTML (multiple lines) from a PHP function?

In particular, new lines and tabs. Obviously, I want the HTML tags behind-the-scenes to look good with the proper new lines and tabs. However, depending on when I call the PHP function that is printing the HTML, I might need to start the tabs at 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. I don't want to have to pass the starting tab count to the PHP function that is printing the HTML.

So, does anyone know a general-purpose way to print HTML-friendly code with PHP? Or is there a design principle that I am missing that says, "Don't print multiple HTML lines from a PHP function." ...

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Markup Cleanup

There are some wonderful codetools out there that will cleanup (ie, adjust spacing) and repair (ie, close open tags).

**Tidy** is one of the more popular html cleanup/repair tools. You can parse your script's output through Tidy on-the-fly using php's output buffers.

Zend Dev Zone Intro - http://devzone.zend.com/article/761
Tidy Docs in PHP Manual - http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

And now, a trivial example, yay!

```
<?php
ob_start();

echo '<div><b> messy</b> <div> <i>blarg</I></div>';
echo '  <div>code rawr!</div>';

$output = ob_get_clean();

$tidy = tidy_parse_string($output);
tidy_clean_repair($tidy);
echo $tidy;
?>
```

### Templating System

You should be using a templating system to separate the logic (php code) and presentation (html/markup/etc) parts of your application.

Using this practice has many advantages including, among other things, making your code easier to maintain and debug.

This is a huge topic of discussion, and almost always goes into frameworks and MVC. There are thousands of resources, here are a few :P

**Writing a Template System in PHP** - http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Display-Tutorials/Writing-a-Template-System-in-PHP/
**Separation of Business Logic from Presentation Logic in Web Applications** - http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=21

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother. With DOM-inspection tools like Firebug readily available, there's no point wasting time on making something designed for a computer to read look good. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304055/do-you-generate-nicely-formatted-html) for other people's opinions on the matter too.

Comment: I think you forgot a link on "this question". Thanks.

Comment: +1 for Firebug, every valid HTML/XML can be parsed, formatting is wasting time

Answer (score 1):

if you're generating valid xhtml, you can [buffer your output](http://fr.php.net/ob_start) and at the end, do that:

```
$dom = new DomDocument (('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHtml (ob_get_clean ());
$dom->formatOutput = true; 
echo $dom->saveXML ();
```

if you're using a framework you can probably make this work as a plugin or filter.
this way it's also work if you embed template into other template or use output from helper

Answer (score 0):

Generating your HTML using a template system, and keeping your templates in order is a simple way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be printing html with php. Use php's shorthand syntax inside of a template.

```
<h1><?= $page_title ?></h1>
<p><?= page_content ?></p>
```

instead of

```
<?php

echo "<h1>" . $page_title . "</h1>";
echo "<p>" . $page_content . "</p>";

?>
```

Comment: Wow that makes so little sense. "You shouldn't be printing HTML with PHP, print it with PHP in another PHP file."

Comment: @nickf - if you look carefully youll see im not printing html at all.

Comment: what do you think `$page_content` and `$page_title` are?

Comment: @nickf - "HTML is written in the form of HTML elements consisting of tags, enclosed in angle brackets (like <html>)" `$page_content` is marked up by html, it is not itself html.

Comment: The question is clearly about how to neatly format HTML code with PHP. I don't think it's much of a stretch of the imagination to see that the HTML would be generated in PHP and stored into a variable named something like `$page_content`. eg: `$page_content = "Hello <em>World</em>."`